# What type of dynamic import in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

typescript:2.7.1

path: xxx/xx

```
export default class Com extends React.Component {
  ... 
}
```

dynamic import

```
let foo:Promise<any> = import('xxx/xx'); // right
```

But I want to know the specific type of generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to let the compiler infer this for you:

```
// foo will be inferred to a promise that returns an object of the module type 
// If you hover in vscode over foo you will see Promise<typeof "path to xxx">
let foo = import('./xxx);
```

If you really need the type, you can statically import the module and use `typeof` as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19559). As long as you don't use the static import of the module no import statement will be generated:

```
import * as unusedModuleImport from "./xxx"; // will be ommited as long as you don't use it
type ModuleType = typeof unusedModuleImport; 
let foo: Promise<ModuleType> = import('./xxx);
```

**Note**

The answer above is the best workaround before Typescript 2.9. Typescript 2.9 add support for [import types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/)

```
export async function bar() {
    let foo: typeof import("./foo") = await import("./foo");
}
```